# contact form in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to ask you for help.

I created a contact form in HTML and JavaScript, but when I try to send the email, it just doesn't do anything, nothing happens.

See the code below:

```js
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/*  contact form
------------------------------------------------------*/

$('form#contactForm button.submit').click(function() {

  $('#image-loader').fadeIn();

  var contactName = $('#contactForm #contactName').val();
  var contactEmail = $('#contactForm #contactEmail').val();
  var contactSubject = $('#contactForm #contactSubject').val();
  var contactMessage = $('#contactForm #contactMessage').val();

  var data = 'contactName=' + contactName + '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail +
    '&contactSubject=' + contactSubject + '&contactMessage=' + contactMessage;

  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(msg) {

      // Message was sent
      if (msg == 'OK') {
        $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
        $('#message-warning').hide();
        $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
        $('#message-success').fadeIn();
      }
      // There was an error
      else {
        $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
        $('#message-warning').html(msg);
        $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
      }

    }

  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- form -->
<form action="mailto:yuridiamond@icloud.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
  <fieldset>

    <div>
      <label for="contactName">Nome <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactName" name="contactName">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="contactEmail">E-mail <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="contactSubject">Assunto</label>
      <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactSubject" name="contactSubject">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="contactMessage">Mensagem <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <textarea cols="50" rows="15" id="contactMessage" name="contactMessage"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button class="submit" action="mailto:yuridiamond@icloud.com">Enviar</button>
      <span id="image-loader">
                        <img alt="" src="images/loader.gif">
                     </span>
    </div> -->

  </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- Form End -->
```

I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

I apologize if it's a simple problem, but I'm still new to programming.

Comment: First of all delete action in the form and into the button, second you need to prevent submit form.

Comment: Please share the code from this file - sendEmail.php.

Comment: the jquery is capturing the control of the form when you click the submit button, the return false maybe is stopping the send email of the form ? What is doing the ajax , it send another time the email?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.submit').click(function() {
$('#image-loader').fadeIn();
var contactName = $('#contactForm #contactName').val();
var contactEmail = $('#contactForm #contactEmail').val();
var contactSubject = $('#contactForm #contactSubject').val();
var contactMessage = $('#contactForm #contactMessage').val();
var data = 'contactName=' + contactName + '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail +
'&contactSubject=' + contactSubject + '&contactMessage=' + contactMessage;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
data: data,
success: function(msg) {
if (msg == 'OK') {
$('#image-loader').fadeOut();
$('#message-warning').hide();
$('#contactForm').fadeOut();
$('#message-success').fadeIn();
}
else {
$('#image-loader').fadeOut();
$('#message-warning').html(msg);
$('#message-warning').fadeIn();
}
}
});
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. My form works with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, faster, simpler and very cool.

See the code below:

```
               <form action="https://formspree.io/f/mbjwrqov" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
                    <fieldset>

                  <div>
                           <label for="contactName">Nome <span class="required">*</span></label>
                           <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactName" name="Nome">
                  </div>

                  <div>
                           <label for="contactEmail">E-mail <span class="required">*</span></label>
                           <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactEmail" name="Email">
                  </div>

                  <div>
                           <label for="contactSubject">Assunto</label>
                           <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactSubject" name="Assunto">
                  </div>

                  <div>
                     <label for="contactMessage">Mensagem <span class="required">*</span></label>
                     <textarea cols="50" rows="15" id="contactMessage" name="Mensagem"></textarea>
                  </div>

                  <div>
                     <button class="submit">Enviar</button>
                     <span id="image-loader">
                        <img alt="" src="images/loader.gif">
                     </span>
                  </div>

                    </fieldset>
                   </form>
              <!-- Form End -->
```

Formspree
http://formspree.io/

The site itself already creates HTML, and I just had to comment on the JavaScript part so as not to give problem or conflict.

Basically, the site already does the intermediary.

A note: The site I created is hosted on GitHub Pages.